# Navigating to elements using HTML Tags in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<a class="page-link" title="Next Page" data-tracking-control-name="nextPageBottom" data-page-number="2" href="/recruiter/smartsearch/history?searchHistoryId=9593411973&amp;searchCacheKey=a2c2df05-f77f-493f-8dae-bc869b6a2451%2CGXJl&amp;searchRequestId=6b3f2672-1089-4677-80b6-f7fa555084f7%2Cr9jK&amp;searchSessionId=9593411973&amp;linkContext=Controller%3AsmartSearch%2CAction%3Asearch%2CID%3A9593411973&amp;doExplain=false&amp;origin=PAGE&amp;start=25" rel="next"><li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><g class="large-icon" style="fill: currentColor">
        <path d="M14,12L8,3.06,9.55,2l6.19,9.15a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0,1.69L9.55,22,8,20.94Z"></path>
      </g></svg></li-icon><span class="hide-a11y">Next Page</span></a>
```

I need to navigate to this element using Driver.find....Cant use xpath.Is there a way?And there are many other  tags in html code.need to use a attribute of this tag as well to make it a unique identifier for this particular tag only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but found the answer.Locating using css selector will work.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pagination > div > ul > li.next > a")
```